# How to get pixel data out of an IDXGISurface created with GPU access only?

Tags: winapi, screen-capture, c++-winrt, dxgi

In broad strokes, what I'm trying to accomplish is capture (part of) the screen and transform the capture into a digital image format. The following steps outline what I believe to be the solution:

1. Set up a [`Direct3D11CaptureFramePool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.capture.direct3d11captureframepool) and subscribe to its [`FrameArrived`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.capture.direct3d11captureframepool.framearrived) event
2. Gain access to the pixel data in the `FrameArrived` event delegate
3. Pass image data into the [Windows Imaging Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-lh) to do the encoding

My issue is with step 2: While I can get the captured frame, gaining CPU read access to the surface fails. This my `FrameArrived` event delegate implementation (full repro below):

```cpp
void on_frame_arrived(Direct3D11CaptureFramePool const& frame_pool, winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const&)
{
    if (auto const frame = frame_pool.TryGetNextFrame())
    {
        if (auto const surface = frame.Surface())
        {
            if (auto const interop = surface.as<::Windows::Graphics::DirectX::Direct3D11::IDirect3DDxgiInterfaceAccess>())
            {
                com_ptr<IDXGISurface> dxgi_surface { nullptr };
                check_hresult(interop->GetInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&dxgi_surface)));

                DXGI_MAPPED_RECT info = {};
                // Fails with `E_INVALIDARG`
                check_hresult(dxgi_surface->Map(&info, DXGI_MAP_READ));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The [`Map()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi/nf-dxgi-idxgisurface-map) call is failing with `E_INVALIDARG`, and the [debug layer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/using-the-debug-layer-to-test-apps) offers additional, helpful error diagnostics:

> DXGI ERROR: IDXGISurface::Map: This object was not created with CPUAccess flags that allow CPU access. [ MISCELLANEOUS ERROR #42: ]

So, now that I know what's wrong, how do I solve this? Specifically, how do I pull the pixel data out of a surface created with GPU access only?

---

Following is a full repro. It was originally created using the *"Windows Console Application (C++/WinRT)"* project template. The only change applied is *"Precompiled Header: Use (/Yu)"* → *"Precompiled Header: Not Using Precompiled Headers"*, to keep this a single file.

It creates a command line application that expects a window handle as its only argument, in decimal, hex, or octal.

```cpp
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Graphics.Capture.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Graphics.DirectX.Direct3D11.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Graphics.DirectX.h>

#include <Windows.Graphics.Capture.Interop.h>
#include <windows.graphics.capture.h>
#include <windows.graphics.directx.direct3d11.interop.h>

#include <Windows.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <dxgi.h>

#include <cstdint>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>


using namespace winrt;
using namespace winrt::Windows::Graphics::Capture;
using namespace winrt::Windows::Graphics::DirectX;
using namespace winrt::Windows::Graphics::DirectX::Direct3D11;


void on_frame_arrived(Direct3D11CaptureFramePool const& frame_pool, winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const&)
{
    wprintf(L"Frame arrived.\n");

    if (auto const frame = frame_pool.TryGetNextFrame())
    {
        if (auto const surface = frame.Surface())
        {
            if (auto const interop = surface.as<::Windows::Graphics::DirectX::Direct3D11::IDirect3DDxgiInterfaceAccess>())
            {
                com_ptr<IDXGISurface> dxgi_surface { nullptr };
                check_hresult(interop->GetInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&dxgi_surface)));

                DXGI_MAPPED_RECT info = {};
                // This is failing with `E_INVALIDARG`
                check_hresult(dxgi_surface->Map(&info, DXGI_MAP_READ));
            }
        }
    }
}


int wmain(int argc, wchar_t const* argv[])
{
    init_apartment(apartment_type::single_threaded);

    // Validate input
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        wprintf(L"Usage: %s <HWND>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    auto const target = reinterpret_cast<HWND>(static_cast<intptr_t>(std::stoi(argv[1], nullptr, 0)));

    // Get `GraphicsCaptureItem` for `HWND`
    auto interop = get_activation_factory<GraphicsCaptureItem, IGraphicsCaptureItemInterop>();

    ::ABI::Windows::Graphics::Capture::IGraphicsCaptureItem* capture_item_abi { nullptr };
    check_hresult(interop->CreateForWindow(target, IID_PPV_ARGS(&capture_item_abi)));
    // Move raw pointer into smart pointer
    GraphicsCaptureItem const capture_item { capture_item_abi, take_ownership_from_abi };

    // Create D3D device and request the `IDXGIDevice` interface...
    com_ptr<ID3D11Device> device = { nullptr };
    check_hresult(::D3D11CreateDevice(nullptr, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, nullptr,
                                      D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT | D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG, nullptr, 0,
                                      D3D11_SDK_VERSION, device.put(), nullptr, nullptr));
    auto dxgi_device = device.as<IDXGIDevice>();
    // ... so that we can get an `IDirect3DDevice` (the capture frame pool
    // speaks WinRT only)
    com_ptr<IInspectable> d3d_device_interop { nullptr };
    check_hresult(::CreateDirect3D11DeviceFromDXGIDevice(dxgi_device.get(), d3d_device_interop.put()));
    auto d3d_device = d3d_device_interop.as<IDirect3DDevice>();

    // Create a capture frame pool and capture session
    auto const pool = Direct3D11CaptureFramePool::Create(d3d_device, DirectXPixelFormat::B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized, 1,
                                                         capture_item.Size());
    auto const session = pool.CreateCaptureSession(capture_item);
    [[maybe_unused]] auto const event_guard = pool.FrameArrived(auto_revoke, &on_frame_arrived);

    // Start capturing
    session.StartCapture();

    // Have the system spin up a message loop for us
    ::MessageBoxW(nullptr, L"Stop capturing", L"Capturing...", MB_OK);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must [create a 2D texture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11device-createtexture2d) that can be [accessed by the CPU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/ne-d3d11-d3d11_cpu_access_flag) and [copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11devicecontext-copyresource) the source frame into this 2D texture, which you can then [Map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11devicecontext-map). For example:

```
void on_frame_arrived(Direct3D11CaptureFramePool const& frame_pool, winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const&)
{
  wprintf(L"Frame arrived.\n");

  if (auto const frame = frame_pool.TryGetNextFrame())
  {
    if (auto const surface = frame.Surface())
    {
      if (auto const interop = surface.as<::Windows::Graphics::DirectX::Direct3D11::IDirect3DDxgiInterfaceAccess>())
      {
        com_ptr<IDXGISurface> surface;
        check_hresult(interop->GetInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&surface)));

        // get surface dimensions
        DXGI_SURFACE_DESC desc;
        check_hresult(surface->GetDesc(&desc));

        // create a CPU-readable texture
        // note: for max perf, the texture creation
        // should be done once per surface size
        // or allocate a big enough texture (like adapter-sized) and copy portions
        D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC texDesc{};
        texDesc.Width = desc.Width;
        texDesc.Height = desc.Height;
        texDesc.ArraySize = 1;
        texDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
        texDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
        texDesc.MipLevels = 1;
        texDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
        texDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
        com_ptr<ID3D11Device> device;
        check_hresult(surface->GetDevice(IID_PPV_ARGS(&device))); // or get the one from D3D11CreateDevice

        com_ptr<ID3D11Texture2D> tex;
        check_hresult(device->CreateTexture2D(&texDesc, nullptr, tex.put()));

        com_ptr<ID3D11Resource> input;
        check_hresult(interop->GetInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&input)));

        com_ptr<ID3D11DeviceContext> dc;
        device->GetImmediateContext(dc.put()); // or get the one from D3D11CreateDevice

        // copy frame into CPU-readable resource
        // this and the Map call can be done at each frame
        dc->CopyResource(tex.get(), input.get());

        D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE map;
        check_hresult(dc->Map(tex.get(), 0, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0, &map));

        // TODO do something with map

        dc->Unmap(tex.get(), 0);
      }
    }
  }
}
```