# RGB matrix from IWICBitmap with CopyPixels()

Tags: c++, winapi, screenshot, rgb

I need a routine that takes a screenshot of the monitor and returns an RGB matrix to be later used for some image processing.

My understanding is that the [Desktop Duplication API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddxgi/desktop-dup-api) is the best way to achieve such thing on Windows (used by OBS for example).

I have found many examples of such thing online, but all of them take the screenshot and save it to file or something else, without extracting the actual RGB values. I took [one](https://github.com/GERD0GDU/dxgi_desktop_capture) of them and tried to extend it.

The last function called in that example is **SaveImageToFile**, which takes as input an **imagingFactory**, a **bitMapSource** and a **fileName** to be used. My understanding is that the [CopyPixel()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincodec/nf-wincodec-iwicbitmapsource-copypixels) function can be used to extract RGB bytes from the **bitMapSource** object, so I tried to implement it but it unfortunately crashes the program with no errors, everything after the CopyPixel call doesn't execute.

[Original code.](https://github.com/GERD0GDU/dxgi_desktop_capture/blob/master/dxgi_desktop_capture/DXGICaptureHelper.h#L884)

I suspect the parameters I give to it are wrong but can't figure put what exactly.

What am I doing wrong here?
Is this the right approach to get the RGB array out of an IWICBitmap?

```
    HRESULT SaveImageToFile(
    _In_ IWICImagingFactory *pWICImagingFactory,
    _In_ IWICBitmapSource *pWICBitmapSource,
    _In_ LPCWSTR lpcwFileName
    ){

    // ...
    // ... some initialization code here
    // ...

    WICPixelFormatGUID format = GUID_WICPixelFormatDontCare;
    CComPtr<IWICImagingFactory> ipWICImagingFactory(pWICImagingFactory);
    CComPtr<IWICBitmapSource> ipWICBitmapSource(pWICBitmapSource);
    CComPtr<IWICStream> ipStream;
    CComPtr<IWICBitmapEncoder> ipEncoder;
    CComPtr<IWICBitmapFrameEncode> ipFrameEncode;
    unsigned int uiWidth = 0;
    unsigned int uiHeight = 0;

    // START of my code
    CComPtr<IWICBitmap> ipBitMap = NULL;
    ipWICImagingFactory->CreateBitmap(1920,1080, GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppRGBA, WICBitmapNoCache, &ipBitMap);
    BYTE *screen = (BYTE*)malloc(1920 * 1080 * 4 * 3); // 32bpp is 4 bytes per channel
    if (screen)
    {
        // generate the full screen of pixels into buffer
        ipBitMap.p->CopyPixels(NULL, 1920 * (4*3), 1920 * 1080 * 4 * 3, screen); // stride = width * bytes per pixel
        printf("%d-%d-%d\n", screen[0], screen[1], screen[2]);
    }
    // END of my code

    // ... rest of the code to write to file
    // ... don't care whats here
    // ...
```

Comment: There isn't actually a question here. What's the *specific* problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @IInspectable edited the post with the question, my bad

Comment: That's better, though (as I read the question), the *actual* problem you are trying to solve is gaining access to the raw pixel data. In that case you may want to query for the [`IWICBitmapLock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincodec/nn-wincodec-iwicbitmaplock) interface. That grants you access to the pixel data without the allocation and copy. [`CComPtrBase::QueryInterface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ccomptrbase-class#queryinterface) helps you verify whether that interface is supported.

Comment: The stride calculation is not correct.  It is 1920 * 4 and you need a buffer of stride * 1080

Comment: If you don't want to save an image to a file then why are you using this SaveImageToFile code, which saves an image to a file? In what format do you actually *get* the image from the desktop duplication API?

Comment: Why do you need WIC at all? WIC is to essentially load/save from file format. What do you want to do with the pixels once you have an acquired frame? PS: Desktop Duplication API is not a screenshot API, it's copies frames from video buffer when the screeen changes, it can be used to "acquire" screenshot but the behavior may be different than one would expect.

Comment: @SimonMourier I need to calculate the average color of some desktop tiles @ 30 FPS and send the result to other software (personal project). I already have the code working with Windows GDI, which takes ~17ms to take a screenshot, but sometimes spikes to ~30ms, leaving no time to do anything else in the 30FPS range, so I was trying to optimize the screenshot function by using Desktop Duplication API, which I've been told it's much faster to capture the desktop. What approach would you suggest instead?

Comment: Desktop Duplication API is indeed suited for that (it will acquire frames at the monitor speed, ie 60hz, 144hz, whatever, but note only when screen actually changes). However to compute the average color, you want to do that in the GPU too to maximize speed. Mixing GPU + CPU won't bring you any gain (or marginal). Check if builtin Direct2D don't already have an effect that does what you need. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/built-in-effects or build a shader (Direct2D one or a DirectX one).

Comment: @SimonMourier I have already implemented the average colors with threads and the performance is really good, so I wouldn't touch that, thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: In this case, just create a DirectX 2D texture readable from CPU (staging), and copy the bits from the acquired frame into that texture. You'll then be able to read the pixels (and you can do that in another thread). You don't need WIC at all, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75171099/how-to-get-pixel-data-out-of-an-idxgisurface-created-with-gpu-access-only But still, this is not the optimal performance.

Comment: @SimonMourier I got that working, performance is way better than GDI, thanks a lot! What is the optimal performance method you are referring to?

Comment: As I said, doing everything in GPU (with custom shaders or Direct2D effects which are builtin shaders) and just exporting your final result to CPU, but it's more complicated to code. Anyway if you're happy you should answer yourself here.